# EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\@angular\material\material.d.ts'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, stat

ERROR in EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\@angular\material\material.d.ts'

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts

Module build failed: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\@angular\material\material.d.ts'

```
at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:948:11)
at Object.statSync (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:297:22)
at Storage.provideSync (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
at CachedInputFileSystem.statSync (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:251:28)
at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:70:52)
at Observable._trySubscribe (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:43:25)
at Observable.subscribe (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:29:22)
at MapOperator.call (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:29:23)
at Observable.subscribe (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:24:22)
at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:22:20)
at SyncDelegateHost.exists (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:61:21)
at WebpackCompilerHost.fileExists (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:195:44)
at tryFile (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24075:28)
at loadModuleFromPackageJson (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24157:24)
at loadNodeModuleFromDirectoryWorker (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24098:53)
at loadModuleFromNodeModulesFolder (D:\Angular\Project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24214:13)
```

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: To improve this and coming question (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). And please provide a bit more of information, like   what did you do before the error occurs, what do you want to achieve, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove `node_modules` folder
2. run `npm cache clean --force`
3. run `npm install --no-bin-links`

[read this for more info](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)